# CHANGING THE DEFAULT MAGENTO THEME

Tags: theme, magento-1.9

**Read this fully guys please**

While I was checking in Google for changing the theme I got this [blog](http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-theme-ultimate-magento-theme-tutorial/) (click this link) for installing new theme in the second part of this blog there was a heading "

> How To Install A Downloaded Magento Theme

under the heading in the second paragraph

*2. Copy entire app folder of your new theme under Your_Magento_Installation/app/design/frontend/default/ so it becomes like Your_Magento_Installation/app/design/frontend/default/new_theme*

*3. Copy entire skin folder of your new theme under Your_Magento_Installation /skin/frontend/default/ so it becomes like Your_Magento_Installation/ skin/frontend/default/ new_theme*

there will be another default theme i.e. folder of magento
what should i do now....

new theme i.e. the downloaded also has folders app and skin so
the folder structure will be like for downloaded ex: shoestore/app/ and shoestore/skin

do you mean that i should copy the entire folder app from downloaded theme and put it in this folder C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\default

as it becomes like C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\default\app\design\frontend\default

I cannot understand what he really mean?

*****`Can anyone explain me 
or can anyone suggest me how to install a new downloaded or 
can prefer me any link`*****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new directory in `app/design/frontend` and in `skin/frontend`. And in those new directories, create one more folder, name it as default and copy required files within default folder.
Go to `System->Configuration->Design`. Give the name of newly created directory as package name. Save it. You may need to clear cache. And you should see that custom theme in front end.